# Table taking full page LATEX

Tags: tables, floats

LATEX Code down below:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption{Timeline 2016-2018}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{13cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]

2015 & Samsung agrees.\\
2016  & Case. \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have the following table, which takes up the entire page. If I want to add a paragraph it switches to new page.

[image: Table Page]

How can I add a paragraph beneath this table on the same page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces teh issue you describe.

Comment: Your query cannot be answered without adequate information about the LaTeX document class you employ. Plus, there may be some settings (likely contained in the preamble of your document) that affect whether or not text and floats can be placed together on a page. In short, please edit your query to create a compilable example of the issue you wish to fix.

Comment: If the table is too large (over 70% of \textheight) it will be switched to [p].  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#39020